# error when using (For Each) with datatable

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I try to execute (For Each) loop through records of datatable in vb.net, but it doesn't work and give me an error message (code and msg attach.) it seems that (tblName) couldn't be accepted from vb.net

thank you in advance

[image: Code & error]

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way in newer .NET versions is to call `AsEnumerable` on your DataTable:

```
For Each row In tblName.AsEnumerable()
    ...
Next
```

Explanation: `DataTable` is a very old class of the .NET Framework. It dates back to the dark ages where .NET did not have generics. In particular, the return type of its `Rows` property does not implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which means that the type of the `For Each` variable cannot be infered and you still need to use the old (pre-type-inference) syntax of `For Each row *As DataRow*`.

This has been fixed by adding an [extension method `AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx).